# Advice needed: convert objects of dataframe in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, multidimensional-array, dataframe, type-conversion

I have following dataframe that I try to convert it's data type.

```
In [5]:
df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(data)
df.head()
Out[5]:
             a       b       c       d         e         f      g       
2014-09-10  5.38    5.45    5.35    1769    10000002    34  6651569991
2014-09-11  5.44    5.48    5.38    1863    10000002    34  8147338425
2014-09-12  5.35    5.45    5.32    1792    10000002    34  10549259297
2014-09-13  5.41    5.48    5.3099  2136    10000002    34  9408246021
2014-09-14  5.43    5.47    5.39    2174    10000002    34  9385610951

In [6]:
df.dtypes
Out[6]:
a    object
b    object
c    object
d    object
e    object
f    object
g    object
dtype: object
```

Before the 17.0 update I was using solution:
`df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)` which worked great, but now is deprecated. Now I am trying to use: `pd.to_numeric(df, errors='ignore')` but get error `arg must be a list, tuple, 1-d array, or Series`.

After playing around I managed to come up with the following solution where I use pandas series and iterate each column to have one dimensional array suitable for conversion:

`for col in df:
    df[col] = pd.to_numeric(pd.Series(df[col]), errors='ignore')`

Is this the best way to do conversion or is there a more elegant solution? I am asking as I'm still getting my head around the Pandas and perhaps it will be useful for someone as I was not able to find a clear answer.

Comment: df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x), axis=0) --> shall get what you are looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function.

```
In [34]: df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x), axis=0)

In [36]: df.dtypes
Out[36]:
a    float64
b    float64
c    float64
d      int64
e      int64
f      int64
g      int64
dtype: object
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks, that's nice to know